# How to limit number of order per customer for certain product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, purchase-order

I have a requirement in my website where the customer can buy a certain product only once. If they try to buy that again it should throw an error saying cannot purchase this again.

Please help me on this.

Comment: you can set product inventory from backend

Comment: try to check customer order item before add to cart using observer method.